# Select only numeric characters after a specific character in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a database field that is VARCHAR with data stored in the following manner:

```
DatabaseField
1185731-2148838B
1185731-2148838S
1185731-2148838W
1185731-2148839B
```

I would like to separate this field into two separate columns - containing the numerical digits on either side of the "-".

To get the values before and after the '-', I can use the following

```
SUBSTRING(DatabaseField,0,CHARINDEX('-',DatabaseField))
SUBSTRING(DatabaseField,CHARINDEX('-',DatabaseField)+1,LEN(DatabaseField))
```

Which gives me

```
NewColumnA   NewColumnB
1185731      2148838B
1185731      2148838S
1185731      2148838W
1185731      2148839B
```

How could I then drop any non-numeric characters from the new column B - and it might not be one letter in the column - it could be 2 or 3 so I cannot just drop the last digit from the new column.

Comment: If the number of numeric chars are the same, you can just simply use `LEFT`.

Comment: It's not necessarily the same.

Comment: Will the non-numerical characters always be at the end of the string(s)?

Comment: Yes, always at the end, but it could be one or more non-numeric characters at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Stuff 'em!

```
declare @test table (DatabaseField varchar(30));

insert into @test values
  ('1185731-2148838B') 
, ('1234567-1234567?') 
, ('1185731-214883612WAH') 
, ('1185731-2148839BLAH') 
, ('AYE-CARAMBA')
, ('Stufffffff') 
;

select DatabaseField
, [NewColumnA] = NULLIF(STUFF(DatabaseField,PATINDEX('%[0-9]-%',Databasefield),42,''),'') 
, [NewColumnB] = PARSENAME(REPLACE(STUFF(DatabaseField,PATINDEX('%[^0-9-]%',DatabaseField),42,''),'-','.'),1)
from @test;
```

| DatabaseField | NewColumnA | NewColumnB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1185731-2148838B | 118573 | 2148838 |
| 1234567-1234567? | 123456 | 1234567 |
| 1185731-214883612WAH | 118573 | 214883612 |
| 1185731-2148839BLAH | 118573 | 2148839 |
| AYE-CARAMBA | *null* | *null* |
| Stufffffff | *null* | *null* |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7ae59de03ecf2468dd960642da856c88)*

Comment: Plus one from my side. As a matter of taste I dislike `PARSENAME()` to split strings, but - well - it works in this case :-)

Comment: Thx. Well, parsename can be a risk if wrongly used, because it wasn't really designed for that purpose. But for small strings with less than 5 delimiters it's rather handy.

Comment: Btw: LIke Alan's answer this will break with values without any non-numeric characters... Just to keep in mind :-)

Comment: @Shnugo Well spotted. Actually, the problem wasn't with NewColumB, gave null as it should. But the first with it's CHARINDEX()-1.  So I stuffed that one also.

Answer (score 1):

Like the (now deleted) answer, I would use `PARSENAME` to split the the 2 parts. Then you can use `PATINDEX` to find the first non-numerical character and get the `LEFT` characters from that:

```sql
SELECT LEFT(PN.Field1,ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',PN.Field1),0),LEN(Field1))) AS Field1,
       LEFT(PN.Field2,ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',PN.Field2),0)-1,LEN(Field2))) AS Field2
FROM (VALUES('1185731-2148838B'),
            ('1185731-2148838S'),
            ('1185731-2148838W'),
            ('1185731-2148839B'))V(YourString)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PARSENAME(REPLACE(V.YourString,'-','.'),2),PARSENAME(REPLACE(V.YourString,'-','.'),1)))PN(Field1,Field2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (DatabaseField VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @test VALUES('1185731-2148838B'), ('1234567-1234567?'),
                   ('1185731-214883612WAH'), ('1185731-2148839BLAH');

SELECT
  t.DatabaseField,
  NewA = SUBSTRING(clean.S,1,f1.Pos),
  NewB = SUBSTRING(clean.S, f1.Pos+2, 30)
FROM        @test AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-', t.DatabaseField)-1))        AS f1(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^0-9-]%', t.DatabaseField)-1)) AS f2(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(t.DatabaseField,1,f2.Pos)))      AS clean(S);
```

**Returns:**

```
DatabaseField                  NewA                           NewB
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
1185731-2148838B               1185731                        2148838
1234567-1234567?               1234567                        1234567
1185731-214883612WAH           1185731                        214883612
1185731-2148839BLAH            1185731                        2148839
```

Comment: Good answer, plus one from my side. This will break, when there is no non-numeric character at all... Don't know, if this matters, but worth to keep in mind...

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to check the column against REGEX and remove any non numeric characters in the string. and use that in your query.

Updated Answer to accommodate more length and to avoid char index pitfalls for Column 2. Split is based on first '-' found. Added few examples as well

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnGetNumbersOnly
(
    @StringToCheck NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE
(
    NumbericValue BIGINT
)
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************************
SELECT dbo.fnGetNumbers('21488-d*39B') AS Result
*****************************************************************************************************************************************************/
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT = 1,
            @End   INT = ISNULL (LEN (@StringToCheck), 0)
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

    WHILE @Start <= @End
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Char CHAR(1) = SUBSTRING (@StringToCheck, @Start, 1)

        IF (@Char NOT LIKE '[0-9]')
        BEGIN
            SET @Start += 1;

            CONTINUE
        END

        SET @Result += @Char
        SET @Start += 1;
    END

    INSERT INTO @Results
    (
        NumbericValue
    )
    SELECT @Result

    RETURN
END
GO

SELECT      c.stringtosplit AS GivenData,
            a.NumbericValue AS NewColumnA,
            b.NumbericValue AS NewColumnB
FROM
            (
                SELECT '1185731-2148838B' AS stringtosplit
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '1185731-2148838S'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '1185731-2148838W'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '1185731-2148839B'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '1185-731-21484-#839B'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '1185731-2148yt839B'
            ) AS c
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnGetNumbersOnly (LEFT(c.stringtosplit, CHARINDEX ('-', c.stringtosplit))) AS a
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnGetNumbersOnly (REPLACE (c.stringtosplit, LEFT(c.stringtosplit, CHARINDEX ('-', c.stringtosplit)), '')) AS b
GO
```

[image]

Comment: This would be horribly slow.  Loops are super slow and so are scalar UDFs. If performance is important then lose the loop and change the scalar function into an inline function.

Comment: I agree but it depends on the DB and dataset we intend to query. I just gave an answer related to what's asked. If needed we can make that into a table valued function which is much faster and add it as cross apply and show result sets. We can move data into temp table and loop through it. It entirely up to us

Comment: Made the query to use a table valued function.

Comment: @Nav, that did not make it any better... The combination of a `WHILE`-loop together with a **multi-statement** TVF is a known performance killer... Much better was an **inline** TVF, but this does not allow for *procedural* approaches (that's why it is better actually)

Comment: Agreed. and i never said its the best performant version. I said it totally depends on what we are trying to achieve and with what information we have.

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion:

```
SELECT t.YourField
      ,B.firstPart
      ,CASE WHEN posNonNum < 1 THEN B.secondPart ELSE LEFT(B.secondPart,posNonNum) END AS secondPart
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX('-',t.YourField))) A(posHyphen)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(LEFT(t.YourField,posHyphen-1),RIGHT(t.YourField,LEN(t.YourField)-posHyphen))) B(firstPart,secondPart)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',B.secondPart))) C(posNonNum);
```

The idea in short:

- The first `APPLY` adds the position of the separating hyphen to the result set
- The second `APPLY`uses `LEFT()` to get the first part and `RIGHT()` to return the second part.
- The third `APPLY` will look for the first non-numeric character in the second Part.
- The final `SELECT` adds a `CASE` to deal with situations, where `PATINDEX()` does not find any non-numeric character.